# How to enter an id in a select multiple cakephp

Tags: cakephp, ctp

I want to put an id to my select but I don't know how to do it.

```
echo $this->form->select("alergias2", ["Alergias"=>$alergias],["multiple"=>true]);
```

I have tried it as follows.

```
echo $this->form->select("alergias2", array('id'=> 'alergia'), ["Alergias"=>$alergias],["multiple"=>true]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this.

```
 echo $this->form->select("alergias2", ["Alergias"=>$alergias],["multiple"=>true , "id"=>"alergia"]);
```